# react MapboxGeocoder is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

Everything was alright but suddenly I got this error. I have googled many times but no solution. Can anybody help me out, please?
[image]

Code I have used

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MapboxGl from 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl';
import '../App.css';

class MapContent extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        MapboxGl.accessToken = ACCESS_TOKEN;

        var map = new MapboxGl.Map({
            container: this.Mapcontainer,
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
            center: [-74.50, 40], // starting position
            zoom: 9 // starting zoom
        });

        var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
            accessToken: MapboxGl.accessToken
        });

        map.addControl(geocoder);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='MapContent' ref={(x) => { this.Mapcontainer = x }}>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default MapContent;
```

Answer (score 8):

Got the answer. I must install `'@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder'`. Just type

> npm install @mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder --save

MapboxGeocoder will work well then.

Comment: In case this solution does not work, https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl/issues/123